# get all values of specific xml field

Tags: xml, go

Is there a way to get all values for specific field name in xml file? This field appears multiple times in different nested levels, and I don't know in advance where it may be in document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Decoder` from `encoding/xml` and iterate over your XML with `func (*Decoder) Token`. While iterating check for `StartElement`s with the desired `Name`.